# How do I prove this trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$$cos4x-4cos2x=8sin^4x-3$$
I used double angle formulas and got $$4sin^4x+4sin^2x-3$$ What did I do wrong?
I worked with the Left hand side.

Comment: You got that that expression equals ... ? What does it equal?

Comment: @MikePierce equals nothing, I was trying to change the Left hand side, so I get the one on the right hand side.

Comment: Take care : You haven't to "prove", you have to "solve" the equation.

Comment: @JeanMarie Well the question asks me to prove the 2 are equal...

Comment: @JeanMarie It clearly says 'prove the identity' but you can check yourself. [question5](http://www.teachifyme.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/9709_s16_qp_32.pdf)

Comment: @JohnFire Q5 in the link you've posted has $\sin^4$ on the RHS, not $\sin^2$...

Comment: oh damn, how didn't I notice.. sorry. @ZainPatel edited the quesiton

Comment: I had hints below, but Ahmed has the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $$(2\sin^2 x = 1-\cos 2x) ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ (2\sin^2 2x = 1-\cos 4x)$$ so $$\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2x ~\mbox{and}~ \cos 4x = 1-2\sin^2 2x.$$
Now
\begin{align}
\cos 4x - 4\cos 2x &= 1-2\sin^2 2x - 4 + 8\sin^2 x\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 2(\sin^2 2x) - 3\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 2(1 - \cos^2 2x) - 3\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 2(1 - (1-2\sin^2x)^2) - 3\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 2(1 - (1- 4\sin^2x+4\sin^4x)) - 3\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 2(4\sin^2x-4\sin^4x) - 3\\
&= 8\sin^2 x - 8\sin^2x+8\sin^4x - 3\\
&= 8\sin^4x - 3
\end{align}

Comment: But it is not $8 sin^2 x - 3$  !!!! as written in the question !

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use that $$\cos(4x)=\sin ^4(x)+\cos ^4(x)-6 \sin ^2(x) \cos ^2(x)$$
and $$\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^2-\sin(x)^2$$

Comment: Did you get $$\cos(4x)=\sin ^4(x)+\cos ^4(x)-6 \sin ^2(x) \cos ^2(x)$$ by the double angle or the cos(A+B) formula?